# How to use plugin for Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail execute() function

Tags: cms, plugin, wysiwyg

I want to put an around plugin.

This is the core file
vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Wysiwyg/Images/Thumbnail.php

The main purpose is on the execute function I want to upload a custom icon for WYSIWYG.

```
            $image = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory::class)->create();
            $image->open('media/wysiwyg/test_icon.png');
            $resultRaw->setHeader('Content-Type', $image->getMimeType());
            $resultRaw->setContents($image->getImage());
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new module and define a di.xml file in the etc directory of your module:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail">
        <plugin name="custom_thumbnail_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ThumbnailPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

2.Create a new class Vendor\Module\Plugin\ThumbnailPlugin and define the aroundExecute method:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class ThumbnailPlugin
{
    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\Thumbnail $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        // your code before the original execute() method is called
        $image = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory::class)->create();
        $image->open('media/wysiwyg/test_icon.png');
        $resultRaw = $subject->resultRawFactory->create();
        $resultRaw->setHeader('Content-Type', $image->getMimeType());
        $resultRaw->setContents($image->getImage());
        return $resultRaw;
        // your code after the original execute() method is called
    }
}
```